# Why my CDO.MESSAGE cant send

Tags: html, mysql, sql, asp-classic

My code is for when a user forgot a password. User clicks forget password and it will ask for 3 credentials such as username, id then it will sends a temp password to the email. Now I'm stuck on sending the email to the user. When i ran the code its giving me an error on line 45 which is "With cdoConfig.Fields " saying missing Else. I can't figure out what is the problem. Please help.

Thank you all.

```vb
DIM strUsername, strHealth, strFacility
strUsername = Request.Form("Set_Username")
''strPassword = Request.Form("Set_Password")
strHealth = Request.Form("Set_Health_System_Code")
strFacility = Request.Form("Set_Facility_Code")

IF strUsername <> "" THEN

    ''******************************** CHECK FOR DB CONNECTION VALIDATED credentials *******************************************************************************************************
    DIM mySQL, objRS, rs, mySQL2, rs2
    Set objRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objRS.Open "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Password=;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=**;Data Source=**"
    mySQL = "SELECT health_system_code, facility_code, username, email_addr  FROM *** WHERE username = '" & strUsername & "' AND health_system_code= '" & strHealth & "' AND facility_code = '" & strFacility & "'"
    Set rs = objRS.Execute(mySQL)
    RanPassword = RandomString

   '' mySQL2 = "SELECT email_addr  FROM ***t_user WHERE username = '" & strUsername & "' AND health_system_code= '" & strHealth & "' AND facility_code = '" & strFacility & "'"
    'Set rs2 = objRS.Execute(mySQL2)
    ''**********************************Insert random password generator **********************************************************************************************************

    DIM objPS, psSQL, ps
    Set objPS = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objPS.Open "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Password=**;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=**;Data Source=**"
    psSQL = "UPDATE ** SET **= md5('"& RanPassword &"') WHERE username = '" & strUsername & "' AND health_system_code= '" & strHealth & "' AND facility_code = '" & strFacility & "'"
    Set ps = objPS.Execute(psSQL)
    Set cdoConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration") 

   IF rs.EOF THEN
       Response.Write "<div align='center'><br><br>Sorry, you entered wrong credentials. <br>Please click back on your browser and enter correct information.</div>"
   ELSE
       Set cdoConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration") 

       With cdoConfig.Fields 
           .Item(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort 
           .Item(cdoSMTPServer) = "***" 
           .Item(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = 1 
           '' .Item(cdoSendUsername) = "<enter_username_here>" 
           '' .Item(cdoSendPassword) = "<enter_password_here>" 
           .Update 
       End With

       Set cdoMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 

       With cdoMessage
           Set .Configuration = cdoConfig
           .From = "support@rxauditor.com"
           .To =  bs
           .Subject = "Forgotten Password"
           .HTMLBody = "<br>Testing</a><br><br>"
           .Send
       End With

       Response.Write(RanPassword)
       Response.Write "<br><div align='center'><br>Password has been reset and please check your email </a></div>"

    END IF

    objRS.Close
    Set objRS = Nothing
    objPS.Close
    Set objPS = Nothing

ELSE
    Response.Write ("<center><br><br>Please click back on your browser and enter your information.</center>")
END IF
```

Comment: There may be other issues, but if you're using sendusingport then you should specify the port eg `.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25` . The most common port numbers are 25 and 587

Comment: FYI http://www.powerasp.net/content/new/sending_email_cdosys.asp

Comment: Actually the error message is saying: "ADODB.Fields error '800a0bb9'
Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another" Line 42: which is  .Item(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort  . I cant find the problem with this.

Comment: @John Thank you for the link. It helps me alot

Comment: I think the typlib references are important given the way you've written your configuration settings.  Also, try replacing `cdosendusingport` with `2`.  Here's another link http://www.mochasupport.com/kayako/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=480